# NSWindowController NSHostingView based contentView: Frame size only updated with delay

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I have a simple setup here representative of what I do in my MacOS app:

```
// AppDelegate.swift
import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        TestWindow()
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {}

    func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

```
// BareView.swift
import SwiftUI

struct BareView: View {
    @ObservedObject var testState: TestState
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.white.frame(width: testState.width, height: testState.height)
    }
}
```

```
// TestWindow.swift
import Foundation
import AppKit
import SwiftUI

class TestState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var width: CGFloat = 100
    @Published var height: CGFloat = 100
}

class TestWindow: NSWindowController {
    let testState = TestState()

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    init() {
        super.init(window: NSWindow(
            contentRect: .zero,
            styleMask: [ .borderless ],
            backing: .buffered,
            defer: false))
        
        self.window!.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: BareView(testState: testState))
        
        self.window!.setFrameOrigin(.init(x: NSScreen.main!.frame.width / 2, y: NSScreen.main!.frame.height / 2))
        self.window!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.mouseMoved]) { event in
            self.testState.width += 10
            self.testState.height += 10
            self.window!.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
            // behaviour only as expected if this line is added:
            // self.window!.setContentSize(.init(width: self.testState.width, height: self.testState.height))
            print("contentSize: \(self.testState.width)")
            print("viewFrame: \(self.window!.contentView!.frame)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The size of the SwiftUI View inside the `NSHostingView` is updated based on an EventHandler. **The SwiftUI View is actually resized and increases its size, but the contentViews frame size is not directly notified about this change**. This happens one iteration later (after the window has moved?).
So the console prints the following:

```
contentSize: 110.0
viewFrame: (0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)
contentSize: 120.0
viewFrame: (0.0, 0.0, 110.0, 110.0)
```

Once I manually update the contentViews size with `setContentSize(_:)` function the console output behaves as expected:

```
contentSize: 110.0
viewFrame: (0.0, 0.0, 110.0, 110.0)
contentSize: 120.0
viewFrame: (0.0, 0.0, 120.0, 120.0)
```

So it seems like Swift is recalculating the window only after the code has returned. Since the SwiftUI view has increased in size, but the Window does not know about this, the origin is not valid. This creates a bug in my app.
I can solve this problem by calling `setContentSize(_:)`, but the information about its actual size is contained in a leave view all the way down the tree. I would need to use an `ObservableObject` to communicate the calculated size back to the `NSWindowController`.

Can someone explain to me if this is expected behaviour and if so, what happens here? There must be some kind of "window redraw cycle" that I don't know about.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to capture window resizing as it happens, you could try:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSWindow.didResizeNotification)) { newValue in
    if let size = window?.frame.size {
        windowWidth = size.width
        windowHeight = size.height
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. If I attach this listener to my SwiftUI View in my ```NSWindowController``` and set the windows origin there, my bug is gone. The question still is: Why? Why does my ```print()``` statement in the second to last code line not reflect this change. Is there a race condition? I would be splitting code that should not be split logically into two different event listeners. So the solution works, but it is not optimal. The underlying mechanism still kinda seems like its a bug.